# Remove a Class Element from Third Party Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a third party widget which loads on my site via javascript, take for example DISQUS. Now there is a class element as shown in attached picture below, inside DISQUS. If I delete it from inspect element, that user image / class element gets deleted.

[image]

I want to achieve that in real time on page load. So as soon as page load, my site javascript or CSS should delete or hide these class elements.

Please let me know if that's possible.

Thanks,

Shubham

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery removeclass method:
https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

```
$('#foo').removeClass('classToRemove');
```

Comment: It is `removeClass` not `removeclass`

Comment: Tried this @ testneo1.blogspot.in/2015/07/blog-post.html. You can check source code, but didn't work it seems. Suggestions ? 

Search Code for : $('div').removeClass('avatar');

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to hide all elements with specific class

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.className').hide();

});
```

Comment: this will hide the entire element (and the elements inside it), but will not remove the css class.

Comment: he is talking about hiding elements i.e. "should delete or hide these class elements"

Comment: may be i didn't get the question properly.

Comment: so if they want to hide the entire element this could be correct.
Also, you can add display: none to this particular class witj jquery to hide it and don't take up space.

Comment: yes correct, jquery show() hide() methods also do the same internally.

Comment: Tried this @ testneo1.blogspot.in/2015/07/blog-post.html. You can check source code, but didn't work it seems. Suggestions ? 

Search Code for : $('div').removeClass('avatar');

Comment: try $('div').removeclass()